# How to check whether an email has been used in a website?

Tags: email, account

Suppose I have an email address **abcd1234@gmail.com**, I would like to check whether this email address has been used in `Apple`,`Facebook`,`Twitter` and so on. (`used` means it has been registered as an account).

How to do it with programming? It there any open API ? Any language will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

No. A feature like this would be a security risk, because finding valid account email addresses is the first step in getting control over the account (second step is retrieving the password from somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such api, this seems to be really unsecure thing.

The way I can see for you to do this – try to register a new account with this e-mail address, and view the result.

Comment: but it seems that register a new account programmatically is also impossible.

Comment: @ChenZhongPu It looks like this idea is too insecure to be allowed to realise it programmatically.